# Evaluating $\int_0^3|3x-1|\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

The definite integral I have to evaluate is
$$
\int_0^3|3x-1|\,dx.
$$

The answer I got was $13.5$ only because I solved for the area after where the graph of the function starts to increase after decreasing. I'm not sure how to find the area of the function where it is decreasing since it's a very small portion of the graph. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Break up the interval $[0,3]$ into two pieces, one where $3x-1$ is positive and the other where $3x-1$ is negative.

Comment: Can you show where you got 13.5 from?  It doesn't agree with my calculations.

Comment: I got the area of a rectangle plus the area of a triangle on the side where the function is increasing: (3*1)+(1/2)*3*7

Comment: [Helpful graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LiYme.jpg) (Desmos app)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:
\begin{align}
\int_0^3|3x-1|\,dx &= \frac{1}{3}\int_{-1}^{8}|u|\,du\tag{$u=3x-1; du = 3\,dx$}\\[1em]
&= \frac{1}{3}\left|\int_{-1}^{0}u\,du\right|+\frac{1}{3}\left|\int_0^8 u\,du\right|\tag{split up regions}\\[1em]
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\left.\frac{u^2}{2}\right|_{-1}^0 + \left.\frac{u^2}{2}\right|_0^8\right)\tag{FTC}\\[1em]
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}+32\right)\\[1em]
&= \frac{65}{6}
\end{align}
Your integral may be visually interpreted by the following picture:

$\color{white}{\text{center me please I dare}}$[image]

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}} + \displaystyle \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Hint: }\int_0^a|ax-1| dx = \int_0^{\frac1a}1 - ax \ dx + \int_{\frac1a}^a ax - 1\ dx$$